# Binding. Difference between handling elements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Well some smart guy here told me the thing that i should use binding when manipulating UI items. Well I got along with the binding topic a little, but there is one currious thing that keeps on raping my mind. Lets make an example so i can describe my problem better.

xaml code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" 
                 Text="Text" 
                 Foreground="{Binding Brush1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

c# code:

```
public class MyColors : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush _Brush1;

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the property that will be the source of the binding.
    public SolidColorBrush Brush1
    {
        get { return _Brush1; }
        set
        {
            _Brush1 = value;
            // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
            // is updated.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Brush1");
        }
    }


    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event, 
    // passing the source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Now to change the color of the foreground I can simply write this in code:

```
MyColors textcolor = new MyColors();

        // Brush1 is set to be a SolidColorBrush with the value Red.
        textcolor.Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        // Set the DataContext of the TextBox MyTextBox.
       // MyTextBox.DataContext = textcolor;
        MyTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

Phew finally we got it.
Now lets go to the second solution that I used.

xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"/>
```

c#:
    MyTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

Wha, the same effect :o
So now my question goes.

What bidings give me beyond this thing? Cus at this point i dont see much difference in the result, expect the thing that the first example took some more space and has an even implemented, and the second took 2 lines.
Can anyone gimme a good example where they rly come handy, bcus the msdn examples aren't giving me a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first way (using MVVM design pattern) decouples your viewmodel from the view thus allowing testability and a possibility to migrate to other platforms in less time.

The second way is easy, but it is tightly coupled. Read up on MVVM design pattern to get the full picture of its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

First things first... in your question, you commented out the line that sets MyTextBox.DataContext, so you're not even using bindings at that point.  Then in the next line, you set the value directly to Blue, meaning everything else you just typed isn't even being used.  I'm not sure why you did that, but that's a little besides the point.  May just be a typo but I won't edit it as I'm not sure of your intent.

Getting to the 'meat' of your question, the first way you did things, as previously stated, follows the MVVM, or Model-View-ViewModel pattern.  The model is the data, or the brush in this case.  The View is the TextBox, and the ViewModel is what you call MyColors.  The ViewModel implements IPropertyChanged so it can raise change notifications for listeners (such as a binding) to listen to.

The reason to design using MVVM instead of the way you did it in the second case (where you simply set the value directly in the code-behind) has to do with separation of concerns of your code.  Specifically, the logic of the application and its business rules is separated from that of the UI.

For instance, your business logic may say 'Error text needs to be red' so you can expose a property on the ViewModel called ErrorTextBrush.  You don't need to think about what the TextBox's name is, or even if it appears on screen at all.  You've separated the business concern from the UI concern.

Similarly, the person developing the UI doesn't need to think about anything related to the business logic.  All they need to know is they are defining a TextBox on screen to be a placeholder for error text, so they simply bind their ErrorTextBox.Foreground to ErrorTextBrush, and now the UI follows what the business logic dictates.

Actually one could (and truthfully you should) take things even further and define the ErrorTextBrush in the XAML too since it's related to the view and not the business logic.  Then in the ViewModel, you'd have a property like HasError and you'd set up a trigger or a binding in the XAML which states to use that error brush if there's an error, otherwise use the standard brush.

In this case the business logic doesn't even have to know the text is red.  That's completely dictated by the UI.  Conversely, the UI doesn't need to know what caused the error at all.  It just needs to know there *was* an error, so it needs to show a visual to the user reflecting that.

Also as stated above, the ViewModel is just a regular class, not a UI which makes it much easier to do unit testing against.  For instance, using the example from above, to test, all you would have to do is instantiate the ViewModel, set whatever condition would trigger an error, then test to see if the HasError property is tripped.  You can do all of that without a UI whatsoever.

This allows the developers to work on the logic of the application, and the designers to work on the UI with very little interaction.  They pretty much just need to exchange what the UI needs to know about and not much else.